# Move chart.js function from partial to assets folder in .coffee file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, chart.js

I have text block in main page, it located in ***_about.html.haml*** partial. When I click the link, text replaces by radar chart via AJAX (I use 'chart-js-rails' gem). Now the js function located in ***_my-chart.html.haml*** partial (which replaces first one) & I think it's not good enough.

So the question is: how to move this function code to assets folder in .coffee file or something like that?

P.S. I already try to move it to 'chart.js' file & use `= javascript_include_tag 'chart.js'` but it's not working graph doesn't render & I have empty canvas element.

**views/welcome/_about.html.haml**

```
%div{id: 'about'}
  %h2 About

  %p Some text

  = link_to 'View chart', welcome_chart_path, remote: true
```

**views/welcome/chart.js.haml**

```
$('#about').replaceWith('#{j render(partial: 'welcome/my-chart')}');
```

**views/welcome/_my-chart.html.haml**

```
%div
  %h2 Chart

  %canvas{id: 'my-chart', width: '400', height: '400'}

:javascript
  $(function() {

    var ctx = $('#my-chart');
    var data = {
      labels: [a, b, c],
      datasets: [
        {data: [1, 2, 3]}
      ]
    };

    var my_chart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'radar',
     data: data
   })
 });
```

**controllers/welcome_controller.rb**

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :js, only: [:chart]

  ...

  def chart; end

end
```

Comment: If this is a page specific chart then it belongs inside the page view.  This will keep it from being loaded on every page request and make it easier for fellow devs to find & debug.  The only time you want to try to put custom js in your assets folder is when it is used in more than one action.

Comment: So everything is ok?

Comment: Yep that's completely acceptable.  Think about it like this, when dealing with rails and ajax you would normally use "remote: true" to trigger an ajax response which normally would seek out a view named after its corresponding action.  That view, if you follow rails best practices, would end with js.erb and usually calls out to then render a partial.  In your situation you have simply bypassed the normal js.erb file and added the script directly to the partial.  If you're code is working as intended, it is completly fine and follows rails conventions IMO

Comment: Code is working good, I just think that there is a way to improve it. Thank you for clarification!